# Images are printing "washed out" in Paint.net

Tags: paint.net

I've had this happen before, and it mysteriously went away, but now it's back again.

When I try to print images from Paint.net they print "washed out".  The printer is a Canon inkjet in good working order with new ink resivoirs, and when the same images get printed from GIMP or from MS Word, they print just fine.

There's got to be some setting somewhere that is causing this, but I cannot find it, if it exists.

Comment: My first guess would be that it has something to do with the [color profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile) (e.g. RGB or CMYK).

Comment: hmmm.  I'll look.  Thanks for the guess, @iglvzx